# Can't import interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to export a config file that contains keys and uris:

```
interface Config {
    API_URI: string,
}

const config: Config = {
    API_URI: 'localhost:3010',
}

export default config
```

When I try to import like this:

```
import { API_URI } from '../config';
```

I get the error `Module has no exported member 'API_URI'.`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does `export const config;` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this "import destructuring" only works on top-level exports and not on object properties.

---

So make this work you would either need to **export each config property** seperately like this:

```
export const API_URI = 'localhost:3010';
```

Or **import the whole config** and destructure it after that:

```
import config from './config';

const { API_URI } = config;
```

---

But luckily TypeScript also supports the `export =` syntax to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow. This means that it is possible to **export one object** as a module:

```
interface Config {
    API_URI: string,
}

const config: Config = {
    API_URI: 'localhost:3010',
}

export = config;
```

Or simply:

```
export = {
    API_URI: 'localhost:3010',
};
```

Which will resolve your error:

```
import { API_URI } from '../config';
```